# Changing color of led in sens hat using nodered

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am trying to change color of led light in sens-hat using node-red. I have tried using

```
msg.payload = msg.payload+"\n0,1,#1100000";
```

But it is not working. It generates o/p as:

```
[object Object] 0,1,#1100000
```

and led color also not changed. Can anyone help me to solve this?

I have gone through different documents. But none of them helped including:
http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions.html

Comment: how is `msg.payload` structured before that assignment?

Comment: thanks for response. But sorry that i9 din't understand your point

Comment: you add a string to `msg.payload`. So I would like to know the content of that property before the addition.

Comment: mag.payload={'d':{'temperature':20'C}}. this is the content.

Comment: So you see, it is an object. You can not just add a string to an object and hope it will result in a meaningful value. I, however, don't know in which format the payload should be given.

Answer (score 0):

The command you want to send to the SenseHat node is `"0,1,#110000"`.

You current code is appending this text onto the end of whatever `msg.payload` is already set to. From the comments on the question you indicate `msg.payload` is an object; that is why you get the `[object Object]` text in your payload.

You should just assigned the value directly, replacing what is already there:

```
msg.payload = "0,1,#110000";
```

*Note:* your colour code has too many digits - it should be 6 digits: `RRGGBB`

Comment: Hi,Thanks for response. The message should not replace whatever already there. instead it should set the color of senshat based on the value.